# Inject cronjob once namespace created

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, google-kubernetes-engine, inject

This mainly for GKE cluster with preemptible nodes. Google Cloud would shutdown any node without warning, which leaves lots of pods with Terminated and / or NodeShutdown state. My current UAT environment is a GKE cluster with hundreds of tenants, where each tenant occupies one namespace. Delete all pods with Terminated and / or NodeShutdown state (means across namespace) would take a very time and not really practical as single run, so I think it might be better for each namespace running its own 'janitor' Cronjob. Now, I could create Cronjob manually with existing namespaces, but I can't stop my colleagues to create other namespaces for their tenants. So I start to think of if I could do similar thing just like Istio auto sidecar injection.

Just curious anybody know what documents / github repo I should dig from here. Or, if what I thought might be totally wrong, please point a correct way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I think it might be better for each namespace running its own
> 'janitor' Cronjob. Now, I could create Cronjob manually with existing
> namespaces, but I can't stop my colleagues to create other namespaces
> for their tenants. So I start to think of if I could do similar thing
> just like Istio auto sidecar injection.

You can write your own CRD or controller to inject Job or Cronjob to the newly created namespace by default.

Anyone who creates a new namespace, it will have this cronjob(janitor) running for cleaning up.

i was looking into this CRD or controller **daemonjob** which will run on each of **Node** as **JOB**. Maybe you could take as base and update it further to implement your scenario.

https://github.com/AmitKumarDas/metac/blob/master/examples/daemonjob/sync.py